# How to get 2D array values based on 1D array values?

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> image = np.arange(20).reshape((4, 5))
>>> image
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
>>> idx = [[2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

How do I get the values from the `image` array which coordinate is specified in `idx`? From the above code, I want to get the values 11 (`image[2, 1]`), 13 (`image[2, 3]`), and 19 (`image[3, 4]`). Thank you.

Comment: 13 is at `image [2,3]`. I cannot edit, as it takes less than six chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[image[x[0], x[1]] for x in idx]

>>> [11, 13, 19]
```

Answer (score 2):

(if ya gonna use numpy, use numpy)

Make definitions:

```
>>> image = np.arange(20).reshape((4, 5))
>>> idx = np.array([[2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 4]]).T
```

Solution using fancy indexing capabilities of Numpy:

```
>>> image[tuple(idx)]
array([11, 13, 19])
```

Comment: `image[tuple(idx)]` gives `array([11, 13, 18])` using your `idx` definition. Found at the very end of https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html